# SettingWithCopy Warning

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I'm receiving this warning from python, but I can't figure out how I can solve it.

I'm trying to merge two datasets with columns "Name", "Ingredients", "Ratings". The first dataset has values only for the first two columns and 15 rows (some of which are duplicates). The second dataset has values for all three columns and 10 rows, same as before but without duplicates. My desired output is the first dataset (with all 15 rows) with the respective rating for each row. To do so I wrote:

```py
fulltab = Recs.merge(Output, how='left', on=['Name','Ingredients'], sort=False)
```

Although the output is correct and I receive no error, I still get the SettingWithCopyWarning. Can somebody help? Thank you!

Comment: The problem is not this line but your code above. How do you create `Recs` and `Output`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore all the warnings you can use the following code

```
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```